# Rails 3 class available to view, controller and model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am thinking about creating a new class that does URL shortening that can be called from the view, controller or model. Where should I put this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such library should live in `lib` and you need to require it in file you use it or globaly in `config/application.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always dump it in `config/initializers` unless you'd want to package it up as an independent gem.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the class in /lib don't forget to make sure that it is autoloaded.  In application.rb make sure you have a line like the following:

```
    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: Nice thought but I don't need to require it for everything, so it's better to selectively require it.